# How to update columns based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below;

| ID | Transaction_Date | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Null | Group1 |
| 101 | 2021-12-29 | Group2 |
| 102 | 2021-01-01 | Group1 |
| 102 | 2021-11-01 | Group2 |
| 103 | 2021-11-15 | Group3 |
| 104 | 2021-12-15 | Group2 |
| 105 | 2021-01-15 | Group1 |

Then I have a list of IDs. For example, `[101, 102, 103]`

I would like to search IDs in the list, then update the label column based on the comparison with Transaction_Date.

So, If an ID is not found in the list AND `Transaction_Date > Today`, THEN update that ID's Label column to `Group5`, otherwise, mark as `Group6`.

This is can be done with a for-loop but I was trying to find a better way.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
df['Label'] = np.where(~df['ID'].isin(ids) & (pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction_Date']) > pd.Timestamp.today()), 'Group5', 'Group6')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID Transaction_Date   Label
0  101              NaT  Group6
1  101       2021-12-29  Group6
2  102       2021-01-01  Group6
3  102       2021-11-01  Group6
4  103       2021-11-15  Group6
5  104       2021-12-15  Group6
6  105       2021-01-15  Group6
```

(Note that in your provided dataset, there are no dates greater than today's date, so there are no `Group5`'s in the sample you provided, but I assume that's not true with your real dataset.)